# D3.js: Accessing Object Property inside Array for Creating Line Graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a line graph using d3.js with this data structure:

```
    var dataset1 = [ 
            {"video_name": "Apples", "video_views": 100},
            {"video_name": "Oranges", "video_views": 35},
            {"video_name": "Grapes", "video_views": 20},
            {"video_name": "Avocados", "video_views": 85},
            {"video_name": "Tomatoes", "video_views": 60}
        ]
```

The index number of the object is the x-value and the "video_views" is the y-value.

**The problem:** It is appending the svg canvas, and the "g" element just fine, but the x and y values for each point in the graph are not being detected, so nothing is showing up.

```
        // Scale values
    var Line_xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([0, Line_Graph_Width]);

    var Line_yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([0, Line_Graph_Height]);


    // This is where I suspect the problem is. //

    // SVG path equal to line
    var Path_Var = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i) {
            return i * 10;
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return Line_yScale(d.video_views);
        });

    // Connect Element with Data
    group.selectAll('path')
        .data(dataset1)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
            .attr('d', Path_Var) 
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', '#fff')
            .attr('stroke-width', 2);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: just changed to .x(function... return i*10; and still no luck

Comment: stroke is white, but background is blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

*The index number of the object is the x-value...*: `domain` of x scale is changed to array of input indexes using `d3.range()`:

```
// Scale values
var Line_xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset1.length))
    .range([0, Line_Graph_Width]);
```

*... and the "video_views" is the y-value.*: `range` is changed so greater values are at the top:

```
var Line_yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([Line_Graph_Height, 0]);
```

x value of line is changed to calculate width of one point:

```
var Path_Var = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return i * Line_Graph_Width / dataset1.length;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return Line_yScale(d.video_views);
    });
```

and line is appended using:

```
group.append('path')
        .attr('d', Path_Var(dataset1)) 
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', '#000')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2);
```

`stroke` of #fff is white so you'd see nothing even if everything is right.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tohedo/1/edit).

Using `group.selectAll('path').data(dataset1).enter().append('path')` you would add not just one path but dataset1.length path elements.

Comment: Dude, I want to give you a hug. I've been on this for like past 3 days with zero progress. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You define `xScale` to be `[ 0 - 100 ]` but values are `[ 0 - 400 ]` and out of SVG view, as set in

```
.x(function(d, i) {
    return i * 100;
})
```

Try set range of `xScale` from  0 to 400