# Javascript: Accessing Property of Objects Inside an Array

Tags: javascript

How can I get the integer "100" from dataset1 [below]?

```
    var dataset1 = [ 
            {video_name: "Apples", video_views: 100},
            {video_name: "Oranges", video_views: 35},
            {video_name: "Grapes", video_views: 20},
            {video_name: "Avocados", video_views: 85},
            {video_name: "Tomatoes", video_views: 60}
        ]
```

Comment: dataset1[0].video_views

Comment: Can you give us more context? It's quite unclear at the moment.

Comment: @theg435 I want to use the video_views as the y-value for drawing a line graph using d3.js. See here for full question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128512/d3-js-accessing-object-property-inside-array-for-creating-line-graph/24129533#24129533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want video views based on video name, you'll need to loop through the array and find it.

```
var dataset1 = [ 
    {video_name: "Apples", video_views: 100},
    {video_name: "Oranges", video_views: 35},
    {video_name: "Grapes", video_views: 20},
    {video_name: "Avocados", video_views: 85},
    {video_name: "Tomatoes", video_views: 60}
]

var searchCriteria = {video_name: "Apples"};
var searchResult;

//This loop sets searchResult to the LAST element in the set that meets the criteria

dataset1.forEach(function(obj){
    var matches = true;
    for (var key in searchCriteria){
        if (searchCriteria[key] !== obj[key]){
            matches = false;
        }
    }
    if (matches){
        searchResult = obj;
    }
});

console.log(searchResult);
```

or you could use a library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org#findWhere) to do the same thing, but without having to look at the loop.

Answer (score 5):

`dataset1[0].video_views` would get that

Answer (score 2):

You are working with an array of objects here. It should, therefore, be possible to use the forEach() method of arrays in javascript. You can read more about this in [MD5 Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

The following code snippet should iterate through your array of objects and access the key: value pairs easily.

```js
var dataset1 = [ 
            {video_name: "Apples", video_views: 100},
            {video_name: "Oranges", video_views: 35},
            {video_name: "Grapes", video_views: 20},
            {video_name: "Avocados", video_views: 85},
            {video_name: "Tomatoes", video_views: 60}
        ]

dataset1.forEach(function (element, index, array){
console.log("Video Name: " + dataset1[index].video_name + "; Views: "+ dataset1[index].video_views);
});
```