# Accessing object value inside array using forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, javascript-objects

Hi my first question here. I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
    const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, 
{title: 'title3', id: 3}]
```

From this array I want to extract the dynamic value of title by id. Meaning if I run a function on this I'd like to receive 'title1' when id is specified as '1'. I've tried a number of things including a forEach loop that right now looks like this:

```
albums.forEach(function(key, index, arr) {
        arr[index].title })
```

I read elsewhere on this site that for/forEach loops could be useful in extracting value from an object inside an array of objects. But I guess I don't fully understand how a forEach loop works in this regard, because I'm unable to extract any value from it. if inside the forEach loop I call a console.log (so like`console.log(arr[index].title)` it nicely logs the value of the title property for each element in the array. But when I try to return (`return arr[index].title`) and call the function it comes up as undefined.

So in summary I have these two questions:

1. What is the best way to access a value inside an object inside an array of objects?
2. How does a forEach loop work exactly when trying to access an object inside an array of objects?

Thanks for any input, suggestions, feedback

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130431/javascript-accessing-property-of-objects-inside-an-array

Comment: If you often deals with manipulating data in your application and you are familiar with linq you could think to linqjs

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
const albums = [{ title: 'title1',id: 1}, {title: 'title2',id: 2},{title: 'title3',id: 3}]

var idToFind = 2;
albums.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.id == idToFind) {
    console.log(element.title)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has several ways to extract and manipulate objects in arrays.  Here are some of the most common that pertain to your problem:

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, 
{title: 'title3', id: 3}];

// For each is for doing something that causes side effects
albums.forEach(({title}) => console.log(title))
// nothing is returned
// console output:
// title1
// title2
// title3

// Map is for transforming each object in the array into something else
const titles = albums.map(({title}) => title);
// => ['title1', 'title2', title3']

// If you need to find a specific one, use find
const albumWithId3 = albums.find(({id}) => id === 3);
// => {title: 'title3', id: 3}

// If you need to find a subset, use filter
const ablumsWithIdsLessThan3 = albums.filter(({id}) => id < 3)
// => [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id:2}]
```

To directly answer your question, you probably want something like this:

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, 
{title: 'title3', id: 3}];

const getTitle = album => album ? album.title : undefined;
const idToAlbum = (myId, albums) => albums.find(({id}) => myId === id);
const idToTitle = (myId, albums) => getTitle(idToAlbum(myId, albums));

const title = idToTitle(1, albums);
console.log(title);
// => 'title1'
```

Or, if you prefer an imperative style:

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, 
{title: 'title3', id: 3}];

const idToTitle = (id, albums) => {
  for (const album of albums) {
    if (album.id === id) {
      return album.title;
    }
  }
}

const title = idToTitle(1, albums);
console.log(title);
// => 'title1'
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) To find a value in an array, [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is almost always your best bet.

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, {title: 'title3', id: 3}]

const findAlbum = (id) => albums.find(album => album.id === id)

console.log(findAlbum(2)); //~> {title: 'title2', id: 2}
```

(2) [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be made to work, but it is not generally the best fit for this job.  `forEach` is about running functions against elements.  It does not intrinsically capture the results.  So you could wrap it like this:

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, {title: 'title3', id: 3}]

const findAlbum = (id) => {
  let found 
  albums.forEach(album => {
    if (!found && album.id === id) {
      found = album
    }
  })
  return found
}

console.log(findAlbum(2)) //~> {title: 'title2', id: 2}
```

That code is clearly more complex.  And it obscures the fact that what you want to do is to "find" something.

(It also has a more insidious problem.  If you wanted to find something in a list of potentially false-y values, it will keep searching if the value is false-y.  So if your were to alter this to try to find the first even number in `[3, 5, 7, 0, 11, 14, 13, 17, 20]`, it would skip the false-y `0` and return `14`.)  You can fix this by splitting `found` into two variables, one to check whether we've found anything and another to store the found value, but that makes the code still more complex, especially when we have a `find` method available.)

(3) You could break this down into some reusable helpers.  I won't write them here.  But you could write generic reusabale `where` and `equals` functions so that the code looks more like this:

```
const findAlbum = (id) => albums.find(where('id', equals(id)))
```

That looks a lot more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getTitleById(id) 
    {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) { 
        if(albums[i]['id'] == id)
        return albums[i]['title'];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you know the position of the object in the array, just access it with the position. I.e `console.log(albums[4].title)`. But if you don't know the position you need to go over each and search for the object in question. Then the best way would be to write a search function that returns the object.

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2}, 
{title: 'title3', id: 3}];

console.log(serachArrayByTitle(albums,'title2'));

function serachArrayByTitle(arrayToSerach,titleToSearchFor){
  for(var i=0;i<arrayToSerach.length;i++){
    if(arrayToSerach[i].title===titleToSearchFor){
      return arrayToSerach[i];
    }
  }
}
```

2. `forEach()` executes the given callback function for each element of the array. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

For consistency, you should use forEach scoped, like this:

```
var Album = function(arr){
    this.arr = arr;
    this.get = function(id){
        this.arr.forEach((element) => {
            if (element.id == id) {
                console.log(element.title)
            }
        })
    }
}

a = new Album([{title: 'title1', id: 2}]);
a.get(2)
```

this should return 'title1'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look for an array element that matches whatever criteria you want.

Then if there is a match return whatever you want from that element

```js
const albums = [{title: 'title1', id: 1}, {title: 'title2', id: 2},
{title: 'title3', id: 3}]


const getTitleById = (id) => {
  const o = albums.find(album => album.id === id);
  return o && o.title
}


console.log(getTitleById(2))
console.log(getTitleById(3))
```